# text processing: awk, sed: change a number followed by a character

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a dot file consisting of 100+ nodes, such as

```
n12 -> n23
n14 -> n35
```

I want to increase the number by 1 in the node label, if the number after 'n' is greater than 20.
So the above two lines would become:

```
n12 -> n24
n14 -> n36
```

What is the nice way to do it, using awk, sed, or anything else?

(I can not use 'cut' to delete 'n' and compare the number, because that would delete some attributes with 'n' as well.)

Thanks!

Comment: Would the number ever have more than 2 digits? And would you ever have to increase n99?

Comment: No, there are no 3 digit number. But would also be nice to know if there are 3 digit numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)/$1 > 20 ? $1 + 1 : $1/ge' INPUT_FILE
```

To change the input file in place, add the `-i~` option.

Comment: forgot about perl, nice! this hints me how to do it with sed too. thanks!